# Android Set Mindate On DatePicker Using Api 8

Tags: android, datepicker

So I'm developing and Android app which I am still pretty new too. In my app I have a DatePicker and I need to set a min date to the current day. At the moment I am using the setMinDate method which works great but I need to lower my api level to 8 unfortunately. I have been looking at the issue online by using datepicker.init() method but i can't get that too work so I have have run out of ideas.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You could take a look at the source code of `DatePicker` to see the implementation of `setMinDate`

Comment: Alternatively, use a backported version of `DatePicker`, [like this one](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker), although as a side effect, it'll probably be Holo-styled on older devices too.